# How can I add a custom content pane to a feature?

Tags: 7, panels, features

I have a custom content pane that I'm using in a panel that I would like to include in a feature.  In the features UI, I don't see any options to add it to the feature; however, on the custom content panes page there is an export option, so it seems like there must be some way to do this.

How can I add a custom content pane to a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the recent Features, UUID Features, Panels and CTools, you can export custom content panes without any problems as the mentioned [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1079440) has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as per [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1079440), a bug in features prevents custom content panes from being exported.